# Calling a button from the main running form C#

Tags: c#

I have a program and when it is started a Homepage (frmHomePage) pops up with games to play and there's also a button to sign in(FrmSignIn) if user wants to save data. If the user presses the sign in the a new modal sign-in form will popup but the Homepage never closes (which I intend to keep open). If an employee logs into the game I want certain buttons to become visible such as 'reports'. The answers I have gotten have helped me make the button visible but it makes the program open a new instance of homepage which I don't want since I have the original running homepage still open. Is there a way to make the button visible after the login is successful without opening a new instance?

frmSignIn that validates if an employee logs in.

```
if (ValidCredentials(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text) == true && checkBoxEmployee.Checked == true && txtBoxEmpPin.Text.Equals(employeePin))
  {
   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
   this.Tag = _usersId;
   this.Close();
   MessageBox.Show("You have successfully logged in as an employee.");

   frmHomePage hp = new frmHomePage();

   hp.Button.Visible = true;   // !!!! Does not work !!!!
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, you made a new frmHomePage form that you never showed.  Pass a reference from the existing form instead.  Also, setting the DialogResult property to anything but None will close a modal form, so you should set that value last, and you have no need for the `this.Close();` line because of that.  What's the point of setting the Tag property if you are closing the form?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try what you said.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to set the button to visible in your dialog class? I'd handle that in the main form, depending on DialogResult.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in the frmSignIn that can be retrieved from the frmHomePage.

Since the frmSignIn will be declared from the mainwindow you can access the property (such as isSignedIn). When the frmSignIn is closed (from the standpoint of frmHomePage/MainWindow you can do a check:
`if (isSignedIn) { button.IsVisible = true; }`

So by using a property like this you do not need to create a new instance of frmHomePage, but rather modify the UI.